# Inherit abstract class and don't implement its abstract method. Is it possible?

Tags: oop, abstract-class, abstract

If you have a abstract class and you inherit that class so you have to implement its abstract method. But is this possible to inherit abstract class and don't implements its abstract method.

I got his question in interview and I said No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, but the inheriting class will be abstract too.

Comment: k great but why would any one do that. Any good practice of it?

Comment: it's always boils down to the same thing: eliminate duplication (DRY), in this case, code duplication. let's take the usual OOP example, the `Shape` class. It's abstract, supports some operations. You inherit it in `Quadrilateral` which is abstract too (which perhaps adds some more abstract methods like get angles, etc...), then from that you inherit a concrete class `Rectangle`, `Rhombus`, etc... the common code for these classes is in `Quadrilateral`, which eliminates duplication.

Comment: It all depends of how complex your hierarchy is. The idea of the abstract class is to just delegate the implementation to another class. But the answer is yes, as @karoly said